# Is there someone who has or knows where to find a Ropsten snapshot?

Tags: ropsten, snapshot

My company developed a PoC for one of their clients in 2020 and the deploy was made on Ropsten testnet.

Now the client wants the proof that the contracts were deployed and working but as you well know Ropsten is discontinued and no longer easily reachable.

Is there anyone how has, has access to or knows someone who is keeping a snapshot or a dump of Ropsten testnet?

I already tried to ask Etherscan, Infura and Consensys, with no answers as of now.